# SOQL aggregate functions number fields

Tags: soql, aggregate

Trying to use an aggregate query to count certain records. Now I know that Number type fields cannot be used in `Group By` so I'm trying the following:

```
SELECT Count(Id), Max(Number_Field__c) FROM MyObject__c GROUP BY Text_Field__c HAVING Text_Field__c = 'String Literal' AND Number_Field__c >= 1000000
```

But I'm still getting an error `[object Object]: HAVING expression must be grouped or aggregated` from the Query Editor.

Comment: Your query looks like you want to use WHERE instead of HAVING. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: We want an aggregate result counting the number of records fulfilling both conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the text field in your field list. Also, having is used to find a group of records that meet some criteria (for example, multiple records that have the same name). It looks like you want a WHERE clause instead.

```
SELECT Count(Id), Text_Field__c, Max(Number_Field__c) 
FROM MyObject__c 
WHERE Text_Field__c = 'String Literal' AND Number_Field__c >= 1000000 
GROUP BY Text_Field__c
```